# What is the definition of aggregate volatility, and how to compute it?

Tags: volatility, factor-models, factor-investing

I am quoting the following sentence from Andrew Ang's paper "The Cross-Section of Volatility and Expected Returns". Can someone explain how aggregate volatility is defined and how to compute it? It looks like the author is trying to use it as a systematic factor in risk-return regression models (The way market return is used in the CAPM model). I am interested in knowing if aggregate volatility is also a systematic risk factor.

> we examine how aggregate volatility is priced in the cross-section of stock returns.

Comment: Isn't the paper defining how it's computed?: " to proxy innovations on aggregate volatility, ($v_{t+1} − γ_{v,t}$), we use changes in the VIX index from the Chicago Board Options Exchange (CBOE).".

Comment: Yes, actually it appears later, and I already posted question before I read further. I apologize for that. However, my question still remains relevant. I did not understand why the authors used VIX as a proxy for the innovations in the aggregate volatility. Is the actual aggregate volatility hard to compute?

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, the paper defines how they compute it:

> "to proxy innovations on aggregate volatility, (vt+1−γv,t), we use
> changes in the VIX index from the Chicago Board Options Exchange
> (CBOE).".

The associated footnote shows alternatives and papers they considered.

**You need to estimate (historical) vol because it is inherently unknown and not directly observable from the return data.**

For example, there is intraday volatility (not part of the most common measure of volatility because you only use one observation a trading day) and overnight volatility, defined as the variation between trading days. See for example Ruey Tsay, Analysis of Financial Time Series (P.110 3rd edition)

To compute vol from historical data, you rely on derived returns data (based on assumptions like using log differences of close to close mid quotes from bod ask spreads). For vol itself, you use some statistics of your choice to derive a volatility *estimate* (it's in fact called an estimate in the literature for the very reason that vol itself is unobservable, also visible in any proper documentation of computer code that computes volatility, see for example [R](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/TTR/html/volatility.html).).

A well cited paper from Andersen, Diebold et al. can be found [here](https://econ.duke.edu/%7Eboller/Published_Papers/abcd_hand_06.pdf). It was published in December 2006 in the Handbook of Economic Forecasting 1:777-878. I'll copy paste a section so you don't need to read the entire piece:

> "As discussed at some length in  Sections 1 and 5, the “true”
> variance, or volatility, is inherently unobservable, and we are faced
> with the challenge of having to rely on a proxy in order to assess the
> forecast".

P.s. I think it is good practice to at least read the entire paper first before posting a question.